# Secret key in .env file doesn't work in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, environment-variables

I have a bunch of `secret` keys that I want to keep in `.env` file and reference it in my `app.js`

I installed `dotenv`

In my `app.env` file

```
ROOMID =abcxyz
BOTEMAIL =abc@mymail.com
```

In my `app.js`

```
require('dotenv').config();
var roomID = process.env.ROOMID
var botEmail = process.env.BOTEMAIL
```

When I run `app.js` that uses roomID to send a message, it can't write the message because it can't find the roomID

If instead I directly use

```
var roomID = 'abcxyz'
var botEmail = 'abc@mymail.com'
```

then the program works. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use

`require('dotenv').config();`

your file should have the name `.env` not `app.env` and should be located in the root directory of your project.

You can specify a custom path if your file containing environment variables is named or located differently.

```
require('dotenv').config({path: '/full/custom/path/to/your/env/vars'});
```

In your case if your file `app.env` is in the root of your app, then that would be:

```
require('dotenv').config({path: 'app.env'});
```

Also, if the same variable is defined in your actual system environment variables, then that value will be used instead of the one from `.env` file.

---

I hope this helps.